# How to submit a form to custom url with a different HTTP method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I'm using simple_form gem to build my forms, and I'd like to submit a form to "/messages/delete_all" with the DELETE method. How can I do that with simple_form?

Here is what I have so far:

```
=simple_form_for :messages, :url=>{:action=>"delete_all"} do |f|    
   =f.button :submit, "Delete"
```

This doesn't seem to work, though. It submits to "/messages/delete_all" with POST.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd imagine simple form is rendering just a `<form>` element with a method of `DELETE`.  If that is the case, `DELETE` and `PUT` are not supported in HTML5:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-diff-20101019/
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-fs-method

I thought that `PUT` and `DELETE` were going to be supported in HTML5 forms, but it looks like they no longer will be :(

Comment: But Rails uses a hidden input field to post delete requests anyway. I;m just trying to figure out how to make that happen.

Comment: Ahhh I see... So the framework knows to look for the hidden input field in the request and map that to the correct controller action?

Answer (score 1):

```
simple_form_for :messages, :method => :delete, ...
```

Comment: There may also be a custom `url: some_messages_path` parameter, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507633/how-to-define-action-with-simple-form-for)