# How to define action with simple form for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am trying to define the action "savenew" in admin/photographers controller.

I have tried this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(:photographer_savenew, :action => 'savenew', :id  => params[:id],  :multipart => true ) do |f| %>
```

But the action in the form is still: `/admin/photographers`

When it should be: `/admin/photographers/savenew`

Comment: Is the controller/route namespaced?

Comment: Do you mean:namespace :admin do resources :photographers do
    collection do
      post :savenew end end end

Comment: Nope, I mean [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) and/or putting the `ActionController` sub-class (your controller) into a module (see [here](http://accentuate.me/blog/?p=12), I can't find the link I usually refer to; sorry :(

Comment: Yes I sub classes in my photographer controller

Comment: class Admin::PhotographersController < ApplicationController

Comment: I thought the first argument to `simple_form_for` was the model; why are you passing it a symbol?

Comment: I have just tried different solutions to get it working .

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using REST for this? It would make your life a lot easier and requires much less code. If you're set on using this custom action, you will need to specify the url and probably the method:

```
<%= simple_form_for @photographer, :url => savenew_photographers_path, :method => :post ... # etc
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from reading the simple form documentation what params simple_form_for took. Thanks for including them above!

Comment: `method: :post` does not need to be explicitly defined. It seems simple_form assumes or defaults to `method: :post`