# Simple Form tag produces an error while form_tag doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I was trying to implement the user-authentication example at http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch. It works just fine when I use their code. But when I try to use the `simple_form_for`-tag I get a Routing Error.

For better overview an excerpt from the example code:

routes.rb:

```
get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
root :to => "users#new"
resources :users
resources :sessions
```

sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Log in</h1>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I basically kept the routes.rb and only changed the sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(log_in_path, :html => { :class => 'login form' }) do |f| %>
...
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "button") do%>
  <%= image_tag('key.png', :alt => 'login') %> Log In
<%end%>
```

Here's the Error I get:

`No route matches [POST] "/log_in"`

I get this error no matter if I use `sessions_path` or `log_in_path` in the `simple_form_for` tag.

In order to keep it simple I shortened my version as it's a bit stuffed with class definitions and the like. I really hope you can quickly point me to what I'm missing as I already wasted a substantial amount of time trying to look it up.

**Edit1** Due to lots of messing with this code I used `log_in_path` instead of `sessions_path`. But the problem still persists.

Comment: What is the routing error you get?

Comment: Since sessions/new is the login path, wouldn't simple_form_for(login_path) just post back to itself? Why not simple_form_for(sessions_path)?

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507633/how-to-define-action-with-simple-form-for) has the answer you are looking for.  You need to specify the url and method.

Comment: aardvarkk, Austin Mullins please check out the edit.
rocket scientist - I found this question and tried adding several combinations of path/actions to the tag. Could you propose a sample tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you missed in your routes.rb:

```
post "log_in" => "sessions#create", :as => "log_in"
```

allthoug i dunno if you have the create action on your sessions-controller....

Comment: I got the create action in the controller and your suggestion works. Could you point out why I need the post route when using simple_form and not when I use the standard form tag?

Comment: because in your form_tag you use sessions_path, and in simple_form_for you use log_in_path. They point to different paths. The 1st existed, the 2nd didn't (with POST method, GET was there ok) until you added that `post "log_in"` line to routes.rb

Comment: I changed the path in `simple_form_for` to `sessions_path`. I still need the post route for "log_in". The interesting thing is that it still works.

Comment: Well it's a bit of a pity that I couldn't learn more about the background of this problem but this at least solved my problem, so I will accept this as the answer.