# Accessing Custom routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple_form_for that triggers a custom route instead of the traditional update method and i am getting this error.

No route matches [PATCH] "/ft_update")

I don't understand where this "/" is comming from. Can anyone help me?

here is my declaration of my simple_form_for

```
<%= simple_form_for @time,:url=>{:action=>"ft_update", :controller=> "experiencetables"}, 
remote: true do |f| %>
```

part of my routes file looks like this

```
resources :experiencetables do     
    member do 
      patch :vol_update, :formats => "js"
      patch :ft_update, :formats => "js"
      patch :pt_update, :formats => "js"
      patch :employ_update, :formats => "js"
    end 
  end
```

my experiencetables_controller.rb file looks like

```
 def ft_update      
    @user = current_user        
    @exp_vol = Experiencetable.find_by(:user_id => @user.user_id,:full_time => true)                 
    @exp_vol.update_attributes(work_params)         
    respond_to do |f|           
        f.js        
    end     
end
```

Comment: ... It's a route at the root level, that's where the `/` is coming from. Why not use a helper path, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/7507633/438992

Comment: thanks, that worked i ran "rake routes" and used this line in place of the url

ft_update_experiencetable_path

and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @DaveNewton in his comment, you can directly use a path helper.
Looking at your defined routes, `ft_update_experiencetable_path` would route to `ExperiencetablesController's` action named `ft_update`. You can directly do:

```
<%= simple_form_for @time,:url => ft_update_experiencetable_path(@time), 
remote: true do |f| %>
```

Comment: @DaveNewton Oops! I missed your comment and posted an answer. I am a follower of yours. If you post your answer based on your comment then I'll gladly delete my answer. Either way the question shouldn't be left unanswered.