# How to solve undefined method `to_key' error with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

When attempting to use simple_form, I'm running into the following error:
[image]

> undefined method `to_key' for #<CourseQuery::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f070689bae8>

This is the relevant controller:

```
class Students::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_student!

  def index
    @course_query=CourseQuery.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def course_queries_details
    @course_queries = current_student.course_queries
    @course_query = CourseQuery.new
  end
end
```

The view, views/students/dashboard/course_queries_details.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@course_query) do |m| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= m.input :message ,label: false %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
namespace :students do
  root to: "dashboard#show"
  get 'course-queries-details', to: 'dashboard#course_queries_details'
  resources :students
end
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to custom your form url. You have to do this:

**route.rb**

You have to create new post method to save your form. I try this routes use Rails 3:

```
namespace :students do
  root to: "dashboard#show"
  get 'course-queries-details', to: 'dashboard#course_queries_details'
  post 'save-course-queries-details', as: 'save_course_queries_details', to: 'dashboard#save_course_queries_details'
  resources :students
end
```

Then you have to create new method to save your form

```
<%= simple_form_for @course_query, :url => students_save_course_queries_details_path, :method => :post %>
```

This is article [how to custom simple_form_for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507633/how-to-define-action-with-simple-form-for).

Answer (score 2):

When using ActiveRecord, the `all` method is returning what is called a relation, a collection of multiple database records.

When building a form using `simple_form_for`, you can only pass in a single database record, not a whole relation. simple_form calls `to_key` on whatever is being passed into `simple_form_for`, because it assumes it is a single record.

I'm unsure about your intentions, but you can try this solution, which builds a form where the user can make a totally new course query:

```
<%= simple_form_for(CourseQuery.new) do |m| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= m.input :message ,label: false %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```