# Call a Model Method with simple_form Submit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page on my app where the user selects a shipping option.  I need to have their choice added to the `order.total` in the database.  I have the following custom method in the `order.rb` model:

```
def update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)
  new_total = self.total + self.shipping
  self.update_attributes(total: new_total)
end
```

And the following form in my view:

```
  %= simple_form_for @order, url: charges_update_order_path(:shipping), method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-inputs text-left">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :shipping, shipping_choices, :first, :last, item_wrapper_class: :block_radio_button_collection %>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- form inputs -->
    </div> <!-- choices row -->
    <div class="row">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Calculate Shipping" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

And I have created the following route:

```
post 'charges/update_order'
```

I have this in my `charges_controller`:

```
  def update_order
    @order = current_order
    if @order.update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)
      redirect_to new_charge_path and return
    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice] = "Something is amuck."
    end
  end
```

The radio buttons populate correctly and no console or server errors show up, but the total shown on the `charges#new` page does not reflect the updates that would have been triggered by the model method.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Create an action and submit to it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7507925/4643970

Comment: @MahmoudSayed, thank you for the reference!  I updated the OP heavily, but am still not seeing the model method taking effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method receives a parameter (`shipping`) but it is not using it:

```
def update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)
  new_total = self.total + self.shipping
  self.update_attributes(total: new_total)
end
```

`new_total` is adding `self.shipping` to `self.total`, instead of adding `shipping`. So, unless `self.shipping` already contains any data, it will not add anything.

As a result, when you call that method with:

```
@order.update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)
```

it is not taking into account `shipping` and no update to `total` is done.

To fix it, change `update_order_from_shipping_page` method so it adds `shipping` instead of `self.shipping`:

```
def update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)
  new_total = self.total + shipping
  self.update_attributes(total: new_total)
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

To avoid `Array can't be coerced into BigDecimal`, you need to get the correct value from the options `Array` and convert it to `Integer`/`Float`. To accomplish that update your controller's `update_order` method:

```
def update_order
  @order = current_order
  shipping = params[:order][:shipping].gsub(/[$,]/,""​).to_f  # new line added

  if @order.update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)
    redirect_to new_charge_path and return
  else
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = "Something is amuck."
  end
end
```

- `gsub(/[$,]/,""​)` is to remove currency characters (`$` and `,`)
- `to_f` to convert `String` to `Float`.

Comment: Excellent catch!  Unfortunately, now I'm getting `Array can't be coerced into BigDecimal` because I'm passing in `:shipping` in the view which is giving it all of my shipping options.  How do I get it to pass in the value for what is selected by the user on the form?

Comment: @Liz How are you setting the value of `shipping` in `if @order.update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping)`?

Comment: The full form is on the OP, but it's currently `<%= simple_form_for @order, url: charges_update_order_path(:shipping), method: :post do |f| %>`...which I know isn't right, but I don't know how to get the value chosen in the form...

Comment: @Liz i meant in your controller, the values sent from the `form` can be retrieved from your `params` hash, in this case should be with something like `params[:order][:shipping]`.

Comment: @Liz Which line is getting you the `Array can't be coerced into BigDecimal` error?

Comment: `new_total = self.total + shipping` is getting the error, but it's because the value of `shipping` is the array of all of my radio choices, not just the value of the one that was picked...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144404/discussion-between-gerry-and-liz).